# Github as Source Version Control setup

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

- I plugged Visual Studio's extension for Git
- I installed Git on my PC
- I created account on GitHub

I don't know how to merge my local repository with my GitHub account or can i use GitHub as repository for my project, so as soon as i commit my code in Visual Studio, it will be updated on my account?

Comment: You want to say "synchronise your local repo" instead of "merge your local repo" ? "merge" has a specific meaning in git.
Does your local repository existed before your Github repo ? In any case I would do the sync operation on the command line (see github for this). I don't know the visual studio plugin but on intelliJ everything is automatic, i.e it detects automatically where to push the code.

Comment: Yes synchronize... ok

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a new GitHub repo, and clone it:

[image: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2013-02-GitCreateConnectPublish/5824.GitConnectPublish15.png]

(Look for the section "Clone a third-party Git repository to your dev machine" in "[Create, Connect, and Publish using Visual Studio with Git](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/06/set-up-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git.aspx)")

Then you can do local commits, before pushing when ready.

The idea is not to push "as soon as I commit my code in Visual Studio": it is a distributed version control tool: everything is local, allowing you to create, move, delete commits at will, until you estimate that you want to publish your local history (here: push your commits back to GitHub).